# HSQL: Creating index if not existing

Tags: hsqldb

I'm initializing a HSQL database 2.2.9 via Spring using

```xml
<jdbc:initialize-database enabled="true">
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:./create-tables.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

In `create-tables.sql` I use

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(...);
```

The table also has an index. I'm looking for a better way than always dropping and creating the index.

I tried:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS myIndex ...;
```

- does not work

I can create a function `indexExisting()` checking the system tables and returning count(*) > 0 if the index is found, but if I write

```sql
IF indexExisting() = 0 THEN ...
```

directly into the `.sql` file, it says

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexcepted token: IF
```

Also a stored procedure does not seem to help, as they may not contain DROP statements, as far as I read.

So a solution other than dropping / creating the index would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'd rather run all the schema migration statements using a tool like Liquibase or Flyway which keeps track of what has been applied and what needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you, I will check those tools. The sql-script has another flaw, throwing an exception when trying to drop the not-yet-existing index. For now, I changed it to init the tables and indices via class, where the exception can be catched.

Comment: `drop index if exists my_index` will work in the expected way. However, `create index if not exists my_index on my_table(my_column)` will create an index named `if`. It will have the exact characteristics you intended, except for the name and the fact that it is created unconditionally and will fail if executed twice. Still looking for a solution myself – dropping and recreating the index each time can get quite expensive on a large DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of HSQLDB supports both:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS myIndex ...
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS myIndex
```

Comment: Actually, I'm getting strange behaviour. If I use `create index if not exists ix_test1 on test_table (field1, field2)` I end up with an index named `if` and running the command again I get `object name already exists`. Using HSQL 2.3.3.

Comment: Try 2.3.4, not 2.3.3.