# How to create table if not exists with HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb, create-table

I'm using HSQLDB for persisting a small data, in my query I want to create tables at first time and if they are not exist anymore.

However with HSQLDB I cannot execute the query "CREATE TABLE XYS IF NOT EXISTS" like other dbms like mysql or mssql.

Please give me solution for this case.

Comment: Try to create them anyways and catch and ignore potential exceptions ... would be one solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have to use this way for everytime create a table

Answer (score 24):

HSQLDB supports the syntax like the example below:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyx (a int, b varchar(10))
```

The syntax is supported by recent HSQLDB 2.3.X versions.

Comment: Thanks, however HSQLDB doesn't allow this query

Comment: @JamesWatkins It works also with indexes in version 2.3.4. See [question 18617638](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18617638/3271406)

Comment: Works for sequences too, woot :)